# Conditional entries in Spinner

Tags: android, conditional-statements, spinner

I am trying to populate entries in a `Spinner` based on a selected value in another `Spinner`.

```
Spinner spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object Obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        String str = Obj.toString();
        Log.i(str, str);
        if (str == "B") {
            Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.array.array1,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spin2.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else if (str=="M") {
            Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.array.array2,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spin2.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

I have assembled this code after going through different forums. But this is not working for me. The `Log.i` is giving me the correct city as selected but the second spinner is not getting populated with the new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not compare strings using `==`, and your condition if(str == "B") will never be true.

Try using [equalsIgnoreCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) or [equals](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

```
if(str.equals("B"))
{
    //populate second spinner
}
```